# COMPARTIR INFORMACION DESDE UN CLASE LOCATIONLISTENER A UN ACTIVITY

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion android en donde uso el GPS del celular para obtener las coordenadas de posicion en tiempo real. En una clase creada de nombre PositioningExample tengo un LocationListener del cual obtengo la latitud y longitud en tiempo real del movil y lo que necesito es poder compartir esa informacion al activity principal para poder ingresar esos valores a los textView que tengo en mi interfaz de usuario. He visto opciones como dataBinding o SharedPreference pero no me queda claro como se implementan y no se si existe alguna opcion diferente.

Clase PositioningExample con el LocationListener:

```
public class PositioningExample {

    private static final String TAG = PositioningExample.class.getSimpleName();

    private LocationEngine locationEngine;


    //Personalizar actualizacion y fuente de rastreo
   // LocationOptions locationOptions = new LocationOptions();



    private final LocationListener locationListener = location -> {
        double latitude = location.coordinates.latitude;
        double longitude = location.coordinates.longitude;
        Log.d("Latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
        updateMyLocationOnMap(location);
    };

    private final LocationStatusListener locationStatusListener = new LocationStatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(@NonNull LocationEngineStatus locationEngineStatus) {
            if(locationEngineStatus == LocationEngineStatus.ENGINE_STOPPED) {
                locationEngine.removeLocationListener(locationListener);
                locationEngine.removeLocationStatusListener(locationStatusListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFeaturesNotAvailable(@NonNull List<LocationFeature> features) {
            for (LocationFeature feature : features) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Feature not available: " + feature.name());
            }
        }
    };
```

Activity Map

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView latitud, longitud;
    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        latitud = findViewById(R.id.latitud_txt);
        longitud= findViewById(R.id.longitud_txt);

        latitud.setText(InsertarValorDePositioningExample);
        longitud.setText(InsertarValorDePositioningExample);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar preferencias, puedes crear métodos para guardar y obtener el valor de la geolocalización.

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void guardarValor(Context context, String nombrePreferencia, String valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(nombrePreferencia, valor);
    editor.commit();
}

public String obtenerValor(Context context, String nombrePreferencia) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString(nombrePreferencia, "0.0");
}
```

Cuando obtengas la geolocalización puedes guardar los valores en preferencias

```
  private final LocationListener locationListener = location -> {
        double latitude = location.coordinates.latitude;
        double longitude = location.coordinates.longitude;
        Log.d("Latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
        updateMyLocationOnMap(location);

        //Guarda valor en preferencias.
         guardarValor(context, "latitude", latitude);
         guardarValor(context, "longitude", longitude);
    };
```

De esta forma puedes obtener los valores en una Activity de tu aplicación:

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView latitud, longitud;
    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        latitud = findViewById(R.id.latitud_txt);
        longitud= findViewById(R.id.longitud_txt);


        //Obtiene valores de preferencia y asigna valor a TextViews             
        latitud.setText(obtenerValor(getApplicationContext(), "latitude"));
        longitud.setText(obtenerValor(getApplicationContext(), "longitude"));


    }
```